# Invoking Multidimensional Associative Arrays in Templates

Tags: php

I'm building a small template system and i'm looking for a way to invoke multidimensional associative arrays using dots. For example:

```
$animals = array(
          'four-legged' => array (
                          'cute' => 'no',
                          'ugly' => 'no',
                          'smart' => array('best' => 'dog','worst' => 'willy')
                          ),
          '123' => '456',
          'abc' => 'def'
);
```

Then, in my template, if I wanted to show 'dog', I would put:

{a.four-legged.smart.best}

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried just writing an expression to replace dots with square brackets and quotes?

Comment: In theory, yes. But then my result would be a string, not a valid variable name. It would be "$a['four-legged']['smart']['best']".

Comment: @GWW you really don't want to be doing eval if you can help it.

Comment: @Byron, oh I'm not talking about eval.  Sorry, I thought he was compiling the code first.  One thing you should try looking at is the smarty template engine, it does this by compiling the templates first.

Comment: and would that template system be smart enough to make the distinction between your expected result and `$a['four']-$legged['smart']['best']` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, given a string with `four-legged.smart.worst`:

```
function getElementFromPath(array $array, $path) {
    $parts = explode('.', $path);
    $tmp = $array;
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (!isset($tmp[$part])) {
            return ''; //Path is invalid
        } else {
            $tmp = $tmp[$part];
        }
    }
    return $tmp; //If we reached this far, $tmp has the result of the path
}
```

So you can call:

```
$foo = getElementFromPath($array, 'four-legged.smart.worst');
echo $foo; // willy
```

And if you want to write elements, it's not much harder (you just need to use references, and a few checks to default the values if the path doesn't exist)...:

```
function setElementFromPath(array &$array, $path, $value) {
    $parts = explode('.', $path);
    $tmp =& $array;
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (!isset($tmp[$part]) || !is_array($tmp[$part])) {
            $tmp[$part] = array();
        }
        $tmp =& $tmp[$part];
    }
    $tmp = $value;
}
```

**Edit:** Since this is in a template system, it may be worth while "compiling" the array down to a single dimension once, rather than traversing it each time (for performance reasons)...

```
function compileWithDots(array $array) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $tmpArray = compileWithDots($value);
            foreach ($tmpArray as $tmpKey => $tmpValue) {
                $newArray[$key . '.' . $tmpKey] = $tmpValue;
            }
        } else {
            $newArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

So that would convert:

```
$animals = array(
 'four-legged' => array (
  'cute' => 'no',
  'ugly' => 'no',
  'smart' => array(
   'best' => 'dog',
   'worst' => 'willy'
  )
 ),
 '123' => '456',
 'abc' => 'def'
);
```

Into

```
array(
    'four-legged.cute' => 'no',
    'four-legged.ugly' => 'no',
    'four-legged.smart.best' => 'dog',
    'four-legged.smart.worst' => 'willy',
    '123' => '456',
    'abc' => 'def',
);
```

Then your lookup just becomes `$value = isset($compiledArray[$path]) ? $compiledArray[$path] : '';` instead of `$value = getElementFromPath($array, $path);`

It trades pre-computing for inline speed (speed within the loop)...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you make an is_array check there?

Comment: Where?  There are two `is_array` checks in the above code... Which are you referring to (the one in `setElementFromPath` or the one in `compileWithDots`)?

Comment: I noticed, also, that setting an element erase all other elements.

Comment: For example: setElementFromPath($animals, 'four-legged.smart.worst', 'roochie');
setElementFromPath($animals, 'four-legged.ugly', 'yes'); Erases roochie.

Comment: Ahhh, yes.  That's because what is it supposed to do with the non-array?  What key should it become paired to?  so rather than making an empty key (or numeric, etc), it just deletes that value.  Otherwise there's no real good unambiguous way of dealing with the collision.  But I've also tested the exact call you're making, and it doesn't do that for me (erase "roochie")...  Did you use EXACTLY the code I provided?  Or did you modify it?